# Find the area of the region bounded by lines

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I have two similar problems, finding the area of the region bounded by lines:

1. $y=x, y=2-x$ and $y=0$
2. $y=x+1$ and $y=\frac{x}{2}$, $x=0$ and $x=4$

I remember (not sure) I should equate the two equations for each number but I'm not sure if I'm correct.

For example in problem #1, $x=2-x$ thus $ x=1 $.

But I don't know how to proceed for it. Are the points of intersection in the first problem $(1,1)$ and $(0,0)$?

Comment: Use [$\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting. And welcome to MSE.

Comment: $(1,1),\ (0,0)$ and $(2,0)$. Do you know what the region looks like? In other words, can you visualize it?

Answer (score 1):

1.This is a triangle, with height $h=1$ and basis $b=2$. $S=\dfrac{bh}{2}=1$

[image]

2.This is a trapezoid, with upper base $b_u=1$ lower base $b_l=3$ and height $h=4$. $S = \dfrac{b_u + b_l}{2} h=8$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See find intersection points of $[x-y=0,x+y=2],[x-y=0,y=0(x-axis)],[x+y=2,y=0]$ then you get points as $(1,1),(0,0),(2,0)$ so iy forms a triangle with height =$1$ and base =$2$. So its area is $1/2.b.h=1/2.1.2=1$ try same thing for second or use graph paper . You will get it hope its clear.